# Android Button isPressed

Tags: android, button

I am using "onTouchListener" in Android for a Button.

B.setOnTouchListener(

```
            new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d(G.AN,"ButtonID: "+B.getId());
                    mEvent = event.getAction(); 
                    Log.d(G.AN,"Event: " + mEvent);
                        H.post(RN);
                        return false;
                }
            }
        );
```

"RN" is a runnable where I want to check at regular intervals if the button is still pressed. However, when I use isPressed() function, it always returns me "false"

```
@Override public void run() {
            Log.d(G.AN,"ButtonID: "+B.getId());
            switch(mEvent) {


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                H.removeCallbacks(RN);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Delay = 300;

            default:
                **if(!B.isPressed())** {
                    Log.d(G.AN,"Button is not pressed");
                    return;
                }
                if(!IsIndex) { ........................
```

Does isPressed function really work? Any androiders out there who used it this way?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: no issues with isPressed() - works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Try implement this:

```
B.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                Delay = 300;
                return true;
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ){
                H.removeCallbacks(RN);

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

and you have to import:

```
import android.view.MotionEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure...maybe u should call setpressed(true) in onTouch-method on ACTION.DOWN motionevent and setpressed(false) on ACTION_UP